pySpark select json value column field not found
So below will return error because field 'sex' doesn't exist. Is there a way to return nothing/null/empty when the field is not there instead throw an error? I will not use if to check each field because there are many fields.
    from pyspark.sql.functions import schema_of_json, lit, from_json, to_json, col
    import json

    s = '''{
       "data":{
          "Name":"Alice",
          "Age":28,
          "country":"USA"
       }
    }'''

    # Extract the nested "data" part of the JSON to generate the correct schema
    nested_data = '''{
       "Name":"Alice",
       "Age":28,
       "country":"USA"
    }'''

    json_schema = schema_of_json(lit(nested_data))

    s_j = [json.loads(s)]  # Convert to a list of dictionaries
    print(type(s_j))

    df = spark.createDataFrame(s_j)
    # display(df)

    # Convert the 'data' column to JSON string
    df = df.withColumn("data_json", to_json(col("data")))

    df1 = df.select(
        from_json(
            col("data_json"), 
            json_schema
        ).alias("data1")
    ).select(
        "data1.Name",
        # "data1.Age", #this is ok
        "data1.sex", #this is not ok
        "data1.country"
    )

    display(df1)


Create a list of the fields you want to extract from the JSON and also use a loop to dynamically create the expressions that will return the field's value if the field doesn't exist.

can you provide a working solution?

hello sure, first Define the fields to extract
for example like this
fields_to_extract = ["Name", "Age", "sex", "country"]

Dynamically create the list of columns, using expr with a conditional check:
`columns = [
expr(f"data1.{field}").alias(field) if field in json.loads(nested_data) else  expr("null").alias(field)
for field in fields_to_extract
]`


Apply the from_json transformation and select the columns
df1 = df.select(     from_json(col("data_json"), json_schema).alias("data1")     ).select(     *columns     )     df1.show()
